# how to start and configure a spring base mvc webapplication with jpa, hibernate and scurity

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, jpa-2.0

I am trying to develop a spring based webapplication with spring mvc + security , JPA using Hibernate.
Of cause i read the documentation, a book and other exsamples. 
But because i am really new to spring i dont know which way is the best or is the way which you go with spring 3.1

I got a working mvc project where i created some controllers. And i modified the spring jpa template project with new entities.
But now the more i read, the more questions i get...

**1. Whats the best way to create that mvc, security jpa project ?**
Should i start from the beginning, should i use that mvc template project from sts and add the dependencies for jpa, hibernate.
Or the other way around ... start with that jpa sts template and integrate mvc ?

I found a sample project which looks close to that what i am trying to do https://github.com/making/springmvc-jpa-blank.
But then my next questions start.

**2. Which ApplicationContext should i use?**

AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ? XMLConfig*Context?
I dont know which way i should use. generally i would like the annotation way.

I would think i must insert that code into my web.xml

```
<!-- Configure ContextLoaderListener to use AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
   instead of the default XmlWebApplicationContext -->
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
  <param-value>
      org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
  </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Configuration locations must consist of one or more comma- or space-delimited
   fully-qualified @Configuration classes. Fully-qualified packages may also be
   specified for component-scanning -->
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>com.acme.AppConfig</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and then can i annotate a class with @Configuration, and load other stuff like my persitens xml.?

thank you in advance

Comment: In spring there are many ways to skin the rabbit (do the same thing).  I myself use the standard XML based bootstrap and then enable annotations processing with a one line XML element.  But if you are new to spring you are best sticking to what the example shows you to do, there are many examples on the Internet, each might take a slightly different approach.  I prefer a master XML and I enable annotations processing over the parts I want it to scan.  This allows me to build more complex configuration hybrid.  There is no "one right way" so use what works for you when you start out.

Comment: For a quick start i liked Spring Roo, which can generate a mvc project for you. Afterwards including Spring Security is not difficult.

Comment: +1 to Pauljo's suggestion. I've done this in the past. Once you have a skeleton app running you can then get Roo to remove all its magic code and generate pure Java version of your project and go on from there (or continue using Roo)

Comment: Okay i will try this. One last question. After some month of spring development did you get to this point, where you would say your project is configured right or you dont need such tools as roo to make a project ?

Comment: ROO was a really good hint :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now 2 years later i would use http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/ with this nice webpage (http://start.spring.io/) for starting a new project.